# Is it possible to install different fonts on windows phone 7 emulator?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, fonts

I made a demo application using Silverlight where I have given certain Unicode of Hindi language to be displayed on a textbox as a text.  ऋ ऊ उ ई इ आ, unicode positions are '\u090B', '\u090A', '\u0909', '\u0908', '\u0907','\u0906' respectively.

So when I pass this whole thing as a string to the `textbox.text` property it shows at the debug time as the exact value is to the textbox but when I go through the emulator the display shows empty boxes.

Is this require installation of different fonts on emulator? If so then how can I do this? Is it possible to build an application for Windows Phone 7 which can support different languages?

Answer (score 9):

You can embed fonts in your WP7 applications in the same way that you embed fonts for any Silverlight application as decribed in the [Embedding fonts in Silvelright](http://paulyanez.com/interactive/index.php/2009/12/embedding-fonts-in-silverlight/) blog post by Paul Yanez. You simply check the **Embed** checkbox in the **Text** pane in Expression Blend.

**NOTE:** You will need to make sure that you are licensed to use the font in this way or that it is free for use in this way.

Comment: Also note: The font needs to be in the .ttf format. I have not been able to get .otf fonts to embed properly.

Comment: thanks i tried to embed the font. I followed the process as, i have added a folder Fonts in my solution explorer project node then added a Shivaji01.ttf font file then edited the xaml code of textblock as shown
TextBlock FontFamily= "/wpf7ProtLand/Fonts/mangal.ttf#Mangal" x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Keypad" Height="48" Width="444" i pass two unicodes as string to textblock then also it does show the letters. Unicodes are 'u0905' and 'u0906'.

but this doesn't work.

i followed the process given on http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/10440/33337.aspx link.

Comment: You can do this more reliably (and easily) by using Expression Blend as described in my original answer.

Comment: ya that's true but in my application i m not using expression blend.

Comment: You could just use Blend to embed the font, then switch back to Visual Studio when you're done. The two tools aren't exclusive ;)